# If i changed html file its not updating the browser, After clearing cache also .In Angular and Nodejs application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am working Angular and nodeJs application, When i Change HTML  file that is not updating the browser after clearing cache also . Please suggest me any problem with coding or what ?

Comment: Have you tried opening your app in new incognito window? If so, you can eliminate problem with caching. On change open new incognito window (not tab!) and then open your app again. If you see the same content it means that server is serving you still old content

Comment: but i am not able to  update simple button also even if i delete button element in html file again it will show in browser.

Comment: You would need to provide more information here. How are you running the server? have you enabled some kind of live reload?

Answer (score 0):

[try disabling the cache of your browser](http://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Run angular app using **"ng serve"** and Run Nodejs application using **"nodemon server.js"** 
Now you change html file and update html without catch memory also you update code nodejs file so automatic refresh.

**Note:** nodemon is npm package so install **(npm install nodemon)**